# External Keyboard Layout does not match shown on System Preferences

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

I have a MacBook Air M1 2020 on Monterrey 12.4.

I've just bought the Logitech ERGO K860, which has an ISO layout.

I had a problem that was recognized as ANSI, but I could solve that.

I could set it with the layout I wanted (Latin America), but I am having the problem that the shown layout at the configuration does not match with the expected when using the keyboard.

Particularly, the keys <kbd><</kbd>, <kbd>></kbd> and <kbd>|</kbd>, <kbd>°</kbd> are swapped.

The first one works when pressing the key next to <kbd>1</kbd> (ie, the first key of the number rows) and the other with the one between the <kbd>Z</kbd> and the left <kbd>Shift</kbd>.
This should be the other way around.

Comment: You didn't solve the ISO problem.  The problem you describe is exactly what happens when the machine thinks the keyboard is ANSI instead of the correct ISO.

Comment: I believe that problem is solved for 2 reasons:
1) in the keyboard setting I can "see" that it recognize it as an iso, showing me what that extra key does.
1') Here's the root of the problem. It shows one thing for both letters I mentioned, but they act swapped
2) When it was ANSI, they both did exactly the same, now not. And the keyboard setting showed a "big" left shift and a "small" enter key.

Comment: Interesting, thanks.   Perhaps Logitech support has an idea?  Or you could make a custom layout with Ukelele to switch the keys.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problems a short time ago with a German ISO keyboard. The solution was to try out several keyboard language variants: Spanish / Latin American etc.

If nothing helps you can install [Karabiner](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/)

Comment: Thanks! I tried it, but when I type each key to switch them, both point to the same one, like there were the same. But they are not since they provide different outputs. :(