# MacOS Ventura - switched keys under Esc (|\) and next to left shift (<>)

Tags: macos, keyboard, ventura

I recently updated from my old 2015 Macbook which doesnt received Ventura, so I frustrated little bit later then others.

But guys, please, help me. I literally cannot work on this machine.

Using external Logitech full keyboard, where, next to shift, in my country, should be | or .

Now in ventura, there is < or >.

The | \ moved under the Esc key.

I am groovy / javascript developer and I need || operator like every other minute. Now I have to have it in copy/paste but common. How did it disapear?

When I connect the keyboard to old Macbook 2015 its as expected.

But I have "Czech - Programmer" keyboard. Now there is only "Czech" or "Czech QWERTY"

Can I somehow install additional layout for programmers?

Help, otherwise this device is useless for my job :-( got more devices and all of them except this new one recognize the keyboard with \ | where it should be (where its actually printed)

Comment: I am conbfused - what is Ventura to do with the question as you say you can't use it. WHat exact versions of macOS and keyboard are you using?

Comment: See if this custom layout helps:   https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/9tyyoutllawgq34kxh7c8/New-Czech-qwerty.bundle.zip?rlkey=rszruph2bdmp46kkyv06osnay&dl=0

Comment: Well, the Monterey is working fine. All machines with Monterey accept the keyboard, as expected. Ventura do Switch the keys. Actually a lot of similar cases could be find over the internets.

Comment: Did you try the custom layout??  Did it work or not?

Comment: Actually I did not. But, in other forum, I read an experience with Karabiner software, and somehow, it was my case. I only install the Karabiner, DID NOT set up or change anything, and keyboard was re-recognized and layout is correct Czech QWERTY now.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "Czech - Programmer" keyboard layout by default in macOS. You must have got it from some 3rd party. Did you migrate from your old Mac, or set up as new? I would have expected it to have copied over in a migration.

If you still have access to the old Mac, custom layouts are in `~/Library/Keyboard Layouts/`. You could copy it over from there.

After comments - the Mac may not be correctly recognising the keyboard layout.
This association is held in `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboardtype.plist` If you delete this file & reboot, the Keyboard Setup Assistant should auto-launch & allow you to re-configure.
If it doesn't, you can launch it manually, from `/System/Library/CoreServices/KeyboardSetupAssistant.app`

Comment: If his problem is the switching of the keys under escape and next to left shift, I don't think finding his old layout will help.  This key swapping issue has come up often here, e.g.  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/443011/external-keyboard-layout-does-not-match-shown-on-system-preferences

Comment: You are right! I just check the layouts in both Ventura and Monterey. Both are called "Czech - QWERTY", but the layout does not match. Setting are the same, keyboard is "recognized" as the same type, but layout is different. Crazy!

Comment: Try to get it to re-recognise the keyboard. I'm not completely sure of how you can force this, you may have to delete the existing prefs. I'll add to answer...